# Loop filtering through columns so as to return a list with all columns, each one containing the corresponding rownames that met the filtering criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called "df" consisting of 181 columns and 22,819 rows, with all data being in a binary form (i.e. 0, 1). For each column of the dataframe, the object here involves selection of those rows with a value of "1" and storage to a list. In the end, I am expecting to have a list with all columns of "df", each one containing the rownames that had a value of "1" for the given column. I understand that there are several ways to tackle this, but since my experience with for loops and the apply family of functions is very premature, I would like to ask for some lines of code that could actually perform the above task.

This is an excerpt of the data:

```
View(df)

GeneSym ARID3A ATF1 ATF2 ATF3 BACH1 BATF  .  .  .
A1BG       1    0    1    0     0    0     
A1CF       1    0    1    1     1    1     
A2M        0    1    0    0     1    1      
AA06       0    1    1    0     0    1     
AAA1       0    1    0    0     0    1   
.
.
.
```

And I'd like to obtain the following dataframe/matrix (whatever applicable):

```
TransFac  1       2       3       4     .   .   .
ARID3A    A1BG    A1CF 
ATF1      A2M     AA06    AAA1
ATF2      A1BG    A1CF    AA06
ATF3      A1CF
BACH1     A1CF    A2M     
BATF      A1CF    A2M     AA06    AAA1
.
.
.
```

Sorry for not providing my few attemps to tackle this, they are too awkward to share. I tried the filter_all function using both "any_vars" and "all_vars" parameters but the resulting dataframe either contained all data unfilitered (in the case of "any_vars"), or nothing at all (in the case of "all_vars").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `melt`

```
library(data.table)
with(melt(setDT(df), id.var = 'GeneSym')[value > 0],
       split(GeneSym, variable))
#$ARID3A
#[1] "A1BG" "A1CF"

#$ATF1
#[1] "A2M"  "AA06" "AAA1"

#$ATF2
#[1] "A1BG" "A1CF" "AA06"

#$ATF3
#[1] "A1CF"

#$BACH1
#[1] "A1CF" "A2M" 

#$BATF
#[1] "A1CF" "A2M"  "AA06" "AAA1"
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
v1 <- names(df)[-1][col(df[-1]) * (NA^ !df[-1])]   
split(df$GeneSym[row(df[-1])], v1)
#$ARID3A
#[1] "A1BG" "A1CF"

#$ATF1
#[1] "A2M"  "AA06" "AAA1"

#$ATF2
#[1] "A1BG" "A1CF" "AA06"

#$ATF3
#[1] "A1CF"

#$BACH1
#[1] "A1CF" "A2M" 

#$BATF
#[1] "A1CF" "A2M"  "AA06" "AAA1"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(GeneSym = c("A1BG", "A1CF", "A2M", "AA06", "AAA1"
), ARID3A = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ATF1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), ATF2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), ATF3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    BACH1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), BATF = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner that gets you there:

```
lapply(df[, -1], function(x) df$GeneSym[x == 1])

# $ARID3A
# [1] "A1BG" "A1CF"
# 
# $ATF1
# [1] "A2M"  "AA06" "AAA1"
# 
# $ATF2
# [1] "A1BG" "A1CF" "AA06"
# 
# $ATF3
# [1] "A1CF"
# 
# $BACH1
# [1] "A1CF" "A2M" 
# 
# $BATF
# [1] "A1CF" "A2M"  "AA06" "AAA1"
```

Which loosely translates to: for all the columns except the first one, find the value of `GeneSym` where this row is equal to one.

If you'd like a `data.frame` or `tibble` result, you may want to consider the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
lapply(df[, -1], function(x) df$GeneSym[x == 1]) %>%
    enframe() %>%
    unnest() %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate(i = row_number()) %>%
    spread(i, value)

# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# # Groups:   name [6]
#   name   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`  
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 ARID3A A1BG  A1CF  NA    NA   
# 2 ATF1   A2M   AA06  AAA1  NA   
# 3 ATF2   A1BG  A1CF  AA06  NA   
# 4 ATF3   A1CF  NA    NA    NA   
# 5 BACH1  A1CF  A2M   NA    NA   
# 6 BATF   A1CF  A2M   AA06  AAA1
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you want to consider is making your data "tidy" which helps take advantage of R's [vectorized functions](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html).  Here's one way to do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
GeneSym ARID3A ATF1 ATF2 ATF3 BACH1 BATF
A1BG       1    0    1    0     0    0
A1CF       1    0    1    1     1    1    
A2M        0    1    0    0     1    1     
AA06       0    1    1    0     0    1    
AAA1       0    1    0    0     0    1")

df %>%
 gather("object", "value", 2:7) %>% # tidy your data (convert from wide to long)
 filter(value == 1) %>% # get rid of the 0 values
 group_by(GeneSym) %>% # group by gene symbol
 nest() # "nest" everything into a list by gene symbol


# A tibble: 5 x 2
  GeneSym data            
  <fct>   <list>          
1 A1BG    <tibble [2 x 1]>
2 A1CF    <tibble [5 x 1]>
3 A2M     <tibble [3 x 1]>
4 AA06    <tibble [3 x 1]>
5 AAA1    <tibble [2 x 1]>
```

The list column you create here is actually a list of individual dataframes, but I believe it gets you where you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R method is to get indices where value is 1. Get `GeneSym` based on row indices and `split` based on column indices.

```
mat <- which(df[-1] == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
split(df$GeneSym[mat[, 1]], mat[, 2])

#$`1`
#[1] "A1BG" "A1CF"

#$`2`
#[1] "A2M"  "AA06" "AAA1"

#$`3`
#[1] "A1BG" "A1CF" "AA06"

#$`4`
#[1] "A1CF"

#$`5`
#[1] "A1CF" "A2M" 

#$`6`
#[1] "A1CF" "A2M"  "AA06" "AAA1"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(GeneSym = c("A1BG", "A1CF", "A2M", "AA06", "AAA1"
), ARID3A = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ATF1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), ATF2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), ATF3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
BACH1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), BATF = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```